# Can we play audio and video files using Applet?

Tags: video, audio, applet

I need to develop the webpage which plays both audio and video files. And we need to change the controls using arrows like Up, Down, Left and Right buttons to manage the audio or video.

Regards,
Serenity.

Comment: Is Applet the only technology option you accept? No HTML5, no Youtube?

Comment: I think, I can also try using HTML5 but not youtube.

Answer (score 0):

If these audio and video files are of formats strictly controlled by you, then there are ways to achieve this in Java.  Otherwise Java is not a good choice of language for loading and using a wide variety of media types.

For example, the [javax.sound.sampled package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html) covers things like AU, WAV & SND.  It uses the Service Provider Interface for supporting other formats for which you can provide a decoder/encoder.  E.G. support for MP3s (decoding only) can be added using the mp3plugin.jar of the [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) (JMF).

And having mentioned JMF that brings us to video.  JMF can load and play certain types of MOV, AVI and MPEG files, **but not all types.**  E.G. I have 2 Kodak cameras that can record MOVs, the older one produces MOV files that are compatible with JMF, the newer MOVs aren't.  JMF is 'abandon-ware' that was quite a good API in it's day - it really only lags today because of lack of support for the more modern CODECs (encoding/file types) - and web-cam resolutions.

Having said all that, your inexperience indicated in not specifying whether it is to support 'controlled' or 'every' format suggests you have a long learning curve to achieving this task.  :-(

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I want to use .mp3 format only. I tried with JMF but no luck. I already implemented the task in Flex successfully but would like to check whether I can do the same in Java. I prefer Java first then Flex.